# Fancy indexing much faster than numpy.take?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indexing

I have read in a number of of different places that `numpy.take` is a much faster alternative to fancy indexing, for example [here](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/) and [here](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/numpy-indexing-peculiarities/).

However, I am not finding this to be the case... at all. Here is an example from when I was poking around my code during some debugging:

```
knn_idx
Out[2]: 
array([ 3290,  5847,  7682,  6957, 22660,  5482, 22661, 10965,     7,
        1477,  7681,     3, 17541, 15717,  9139,  1475, 14251,  4400,
        7680,  9140,  4758, 22289,  7679,  8407, 20101, 15718, 15716,
        8405, 15710, 20829, 22662], dtype=uint32)
%timeit X.take(knn_idx, axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.14 ms per loop
%timeit X[knn_idx]
The slowest run took 60.61 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.48 µs per loop
X.shape
Out[5]: 
(23011, 30)
X.dtype
Out[6]: 
dtype('float64')
```

Which is showing that fancy indexing is much faster! Using `numpy.arange` to generate the indices I get a similar result:

```
idx = np.arange(0, len(X), 100)
%timeit X.take(idx, axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.04 ms per loop
%timeit X[idx]
The slowest run took 9.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.7 µs per loop
```

Why is fancy indexing so much faster than using `numpy.take` now? Am I hitting some kind of edge case?

I'm using Python 3.6 through Anaconda and here is my numpy info if relevant:

```
np.__version__
Out[11]: 
'1.11.3'
np.__config__.show()
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/pbreach/Continuum/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
```

Answer (score 3):

In my tests `take` is modestly faster; but with the small time and 'cached' warning I don't put a lot of stock in the difference:

```
In [192]: timeit X.take(idx2, axis=0).shape
The slowest run took 23.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.66 µs per loop
In [193]: timeit X[idx2,:].shape
The slowest run took 16.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.58 µs per loop
```

But your index array is `uint32`.  That worked ok with indexing, but take gave me a casting error; So my `idx2` is `astype(int)`.

And with the arange idx, times are  11.5 µs, 16 µs.

Notice I'm timing with a `.shape`;  I'm not entirely sure that makes a difference.

I don't know why you are getting `ms` times for your take.  It feels like more of  a timing issue than an actual difference in `take`.

I don't the libraries, BLAS etc will make a difference. The underlying task is basically the same - step through the data buffer and copy out selected bytes.  There's no complicated computation to farm out.  But I haven't studied the C code for take.

Numpy version '1.12.0', Linux, 4gb refurbished desktop.

Comment: Strange, in my second test in the question I used an index array of `int32` and still got similar timings with the first.

Comment: Even in the slowest run it was still about 15x faster with `int32` index.

Comment: Good point(s) now I'm wondering what could be wrong with `take` in my specific case as opposed to in general. I'll also try including `shape` in timing as well.